# Button or shortcut for isread:no in OWA?

Tags: jquery, outlook-web-addins

We are in the midst of migrating from GMail to Office 365. I would like our users to use the Outlook web client. Previously in GMail we had created a button that would quickly show a user all of their unread messages across their mailbox. Basically it just did the same thing as typing in is:unread in the Search field. We would like to provide this same functionality to our OWA users but I have been unable to figure out a way to do it. The OWA search term that works is isread:no but I'd like to have a button or link we will add using a Chrome extension.

Does anyone know of a way to pass this search parameter in a way that can be simulated with Jquery (some combination of sendkey > Alt+Q + isread:no) or even a URL+variables?

Thank you.

This looks like it should at least get things started with simulating Alt+Q but it doesn't seem to be working. There is an element with an id of unrbutton.

```
$('#unrbutton').click(function(){
    var evt = $.Event('keydown');
    evt.keyCode = 81; // 'Q' key
    evt.altKey = true;
    $(document).trigger(evt);
});
```

Comment: So I'm trying to work this out in my head. Pressing Alt+Q on the OWA page starts a search with the cursor in the search field. Simulating the key presses for i s r e a d : n o would fill in the search term. Finally sending the equivalent of Enter would finish the search ( keypress 13?) and display the unread messages for the entire mailbox. I just need to figure out how to string together all these keys....